# Is it possible in java to listen all objects creation?

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to set up a default listener called when any object is created ?

Something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setInstanceListener(listener); // this method doesn't exists
    MyObject obj = new MyObject(); // the new keyword now call listener()
    OtherObject oo = new OtherObject(); // same here
}

public static void listener(Object newObject) {
    // do something with the created object
}
```

Comment: To call listener when object of particular class created you can call  listener method from constructor  write  listener(this) in constructor.

Comment: Do you want this called for Strings, Integer etc as well?

Comment: My question is more about to detect instanciation of any object at runtime without changing constructor signature or using a builder.
@PeterLawrey : If you have any solution with or without them I would like to read it :)

Comment: You can do this by Instrumenting Object itself.  The down side are; a) it is potentially painfully slow, and b) of course you cannot create any objects in the listener.  Generally this sort of monitoring is done by profilers where the monitoring code is written in C++. Even then you generally only sample every 10-th object so your program doesn't slow down too much.

Comment: There is no good reason to do this. Do you have an XY Problem: why do you want to do this, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thank you Peter. @Raedwald: I'm coding a small binding/injection framework and I wanted to auto-inject objects just after their instanciation without register them to a context (this is my current solution). I was just asking this question because I didn't find anything on the web/SO talking about that. It was more a general question than a solution for my initial problem.

Comment: Have you try with AspectJ?

Answer (score 1):

If your are ready to use some framework as AspectJ, it's quite straightforward.
Herewith I'll give an example using Maven.

First the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dummy.listener</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy.listener</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <description>
      Is it possible in java to listen all objects creation?
      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839701/is-it-possible-in-java-to-listen-all-objects-creation
    </description>

    <properties>

        <main.class>dummy.listener.MainApp</main.class>

        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
        <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
        <maven.compiler.verbose>true</maven.compiler.verbose>
        <maven.compiler.optimize>true</maven.compiler.optimize>
        <maven.compiler.debug>true</maven.compiler.debug>

        <maven.jar.plugin.version>2.6</maven.jar.plugin.version>
        <maven.antrun.plugin.version>1.8</maven.antrun.plugin.version>
        <aspectj.maven.plugin.version>1.8</aspectj.maven.plugin.version>

        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.13</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile time weaving -->

        <!-- required to avoid warning from aspectj-maven-plugin, 
             even if aspectjweaver is also a dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- aspectjrt is only a subset of aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <complianceLevel>${jdk.version}</complianceLevel>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
            <id>class-antrun</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <java fork="true" classname="${main.class}">
                                    <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                </java>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>only-under-eclipse</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>m2e.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                    <pluginExecutions>
                                        <pluginExecution>
                                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <versionRange>[${aspectj.maven.plugin.version},)</versionRange>
                                                <goals>
                                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <action>
                                                <ignore />
                                            </action>
                                        </pluginExecution>
                                    </pluginExecutions>
                                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Then the main class:

```
package dummy.listener;

import dummy.listener.model.MyObject1;
import dummy.listener.model.MyObject2;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new MyObject1();
        new MyObject2();
    }

}
```

The weaving job is done by:

```
package dummy.listener;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import dummy.listener.model.MyObject1;
import dummy.listener.model.MyObject2;

@Aspect
public class AspectjDemo
{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AspectjDemo.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="call(dummy.listener.model.*.new(..))", returning="result")
    public void doSomethingAfterNewModelCreation(JoinPoint joinPoint , Object result) {
        log.info("[AspectJ] Log after creation of " + result.getClass());
        if (/*result instanceof MyObject1*/ MyObject1.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getClass())) {
            MyObject1 mo = (MyObject1) result;
            log.info("Name: " + mo.getName());
        } else if (/*result instanceof MyObject2*/ MyObject2.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getClass())) {
            MyObject2 mo = (MyObject2) result;
            log.info("Location: " + mo.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

Now add some guinea pig classes:

```
package dummy.listener.model;

public class MyObject1 {

    public String getName() {
        return "myObject1 name";
    }

}


package dummy.listener.model;

public class MyObject2 {

    public String getLocation() {
        return "myObject2 location";
    }

}
```

To finish, compile and launch the main class with Maven:

```
mvn clean compile antrun:run -Pclass-antrun
```

You should have something like:

```
[...]
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) @ dummy.listener ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'constructor-call(void dummy.listener.model.MyObject1.<init>())' in Type 'dummy.listener.MainApp' (MainApp.java:8) advised by afterReturning advice from 'dummy.listener.AspectjDemo' (AspectjDemo.java:18)
[INFO] Join point 'constructor-call(void dummy.listener.model.MyObject2.<init>())' in Type 'dummy.listener.MainApp' (MainApp.java:9) advised by afterReturning advice from 'dummy.listener.AspectjDemo' (AspectjDemo.java:18)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default-cli) @ dummy.listener ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [java] [main] INFO dummy.listener.AspectjDemo - [AspectJ] Log after creation of class dummy.listener.model.MyObject1
     [java] [main] INFO dummy.listener.AspectjDemo - Name: myObject1 name
     [java] [main] INFO dummy.listener.AspectjDemo - [AspectJ] Log after creation of class dummy.listener.model.MyObject2
     [java] [main] INFO dummy.listener.AspectjDemo - Location: myObject2 location
[INFO] Executed tasks
[...]
```

That's it. Hope it'll help.